# Nginx problem when i enabled the file by linking to the sites-enabled dir

Tags: django, nginx, deployment

my gorgeous friends on the internet.
I was doing something about Nginx for deploying my app made by Django, Postgresql, Gunicorn, Nginx, and DigitalOcean.
First of all, The project name in the Github gist is btre_project, but my app's project name is pfc_calc. Considering the name dif, I created project folder by coping and pasting the line on the gist.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/pfc_calc
```

And, copy the code and paste it into the file I just made.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 104.248.152.6;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/pfc_calc;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/pfc_calc;    
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

BUT, here is where I made a mistake and got an error
I was so foolish that I forgot to change btre_project to pfc_calc

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/btre_project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Because I noticed that mistake, I typed this line again.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/pfc_calc /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

I thought it would be ok and my mistake was under the bridge, but it wouldn't.
When I typed this line

```
sudo nginx -t
```

this error below showed up.

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/btre_project" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I think I needed to delete the file I mis-created when I typed

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/btre_project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Any help??

[image: Set up explanation and my terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is because it cannot resolve the symlink to the first conf you specified. If you can remove the `btre_project` inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` then you're good to go.

PS: I tested it on a fresh nginx install and was able to reproduce the exact error you have

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jech!! It worked!!sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
djangoadmin@ubuntu1:~/pyapps/pfc_calc$ sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/path
djangoadmin@ubuntu1:~/pyapps/pfc_calc$ sudo nginx -t

Answer (score 0):

Below is the continuous code in the terminal

```
djangoadmin@ubuntu1:~/pyapps/pfc_calc$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
djangoadmin@ubuntu1:~/pyapps/pfc_calc$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-07-20 01:42:48 UTC; 26s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 9926 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=
  Process: 9928 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAI
 Main PID: 28967 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 ^X
```